# dayNamesShort:["So","Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa"] => 2 letter days

Tags: joomla, datepicker, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have looked up and down but I don't know how to change in the overview module to spell the days of the week with just two letters on this site: http://www.vhs-lengerich.de/joomla

I know it must be hidden somewhere in the `#datepicker` with daynamesmin, but I cannot seem to find either the datepicker (is it part of the `fullcalendar.min.js`?) or part of a module where this can be configured.

Where is the correct place to configure two letter day names, as they are used in German?

Comment: where in the page did you see two-letter days? AFAIS, the page is using the fullcalendar plugin, not the jQuery UI Datepicker one; they do not provide a `dayNamesMin` option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the site is using jQuery UI Datepicker indeed, you could just set the days after initializing the datepicker like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dayNamesMin", ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'] );
```